# Python OpenCV Circle Rant

Tags: python, opencv

To begin with, I'm a bit frustrated with the lack of dedicated Python OpenCV documentation. Everything seems to be coupled with the C++ API which just acts different.

Running the following code with a dash.png nearby seems to make both image and image2 have a circle - why does it both modify in-place AND return a modified image?

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("dash.png")
h, w, _ = image.shape
image2 = cv2.circle(image, (w//2, h//2), 5, (0, 0, 255), 3)
print(type(image2))
cv2.imshow("im1", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow("im2", image2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Is the only way to not modify the original image to make a copy before giving it to circle?

Comment: "why does it both modify in-place AND return a modified image?" - Because that's the way the creators programmed it. What's wrong with the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#:~:text=The%20function%20cv%3A%3Acircle%20draws%20a%20simple%20or%20filled%20circle%20with%20a%20given%20center%20and%20radius.)?

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670) is there, the Python signature is just below the one for C++, I'm sure you've just missed it. Yes, you'll need to make a copy if you don't want the original image changed. The situation would be worse if it were reversed and you actually *wanted* the original image to be modified, but were forced to allocate a new image just to draw a circle on it.

Comment: There’s no Python version of OpenCV. There are only Python-C++ bindings, which you are calling from Pyhton. I agree there’s lack of documentation for the Python implementation, though. Keep in mind the OpenCV has been developed mainly in C++.

Now, most of the C++ OpenCV functions receive a `cv::Mat` object (or `inputOutputArray`) and modify their values by reference. That is, you get the results in the original container you provide. These details are a little bit obscured in Python.

Comment: Finally, is not clear what you want. The Python functions normally explicitly return a container, while some exceptions (like `cv2.circle`) indeed, return the result by reference. You can store a [Deep Copy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) of a numpy array if you want to keep the original data of a matrix before modification, though.

Comment: that's just how the automatically generated bindings behave. for whatever API call, if it _modifies_ a `Mat` given as *input*, then that *needs to be* returned, because it could have **not** been given (e.g. a default empty/resized Mat would have been used), in which case you wouldn't have any reference to it at all, if it had *not* been returned. there is no distinction between mandatory arguments and arguments with defaults (for a given API, when python bindings are generated). -- simply **ignore** the return value of all drawing calls. it's the same object you passed in.